# Javascript - Regular Expressions - Using Not operator

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this is probably quite straightforward but cannot seem to find an example of what I'm trying to do.

Matching from start of a string, i want to match building numbers.

i.e.

60 would match 60A and 60 but not 6000

likewise

1 would match 1 and 1ABC but not 11

`/^1[^\0-9]*`

is like what i need, matching 1 and any non numeric value any number of times. (granted this is from expresso - (.net) but it doesn't work in there.

can anybody point me in the right direction?

thanks,

Sam

Comment: I think you don't need the first bar `/`

Comment: Show some sample string to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\0` means something else

```
/^1[^0-9]*/
```

`0-9` is the same as `\d`

```
/^1[^\d]*/
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use regex `/^1(?!\d)/` to match building 1.

THe `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead and says "match 1, as long as it isn't followed by another number".

e.g.

```
myString.match(/^1(?!\d)/)
```

Comment: thanks for response, but doesn't match 1A? i found ^1[^\d]*$ was the solution i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put a variable in a regex, you can do something like:

```
var number = 60;
var re = new RegExp("^"+number+"(?!\\d)");

'60'.match(re);        // => ["60"]
'60A'.match(re);       // => ["60"]
'600   '.match(re);    // => null
'a60A'.match(re);      // => null
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly what you're asking for, you can do this:

```
function parseLeadingDigits(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/^\d+/);
    if (matches) {
        return ({num: parseInt(matches[0], 10), valid: true});
    }
    return ({num: 0, valid: false});
}

function compareLeadingDigits(str1, str2) {
    var data1 = parseLeadingDigits(str1);
    var data2 = parseLeadingDigits(str2);
    return(data1.valid && data2.valid && (data1.num == data2.num));
}
```

Or it could be done without converting to actual numbers like this:

```
function parseLeadingDigits(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/^\d+/);
    if (matches) {
        return(matches[0]);
    }
    return("");
}

function compareLeadingDigits(str1, str2) {
    var result1 = parseLeadingDigits(str1);
    var result2 = parseLeadingDigits(str2);
    return(result1 == result2 && result1 != "");
}
```

Examples:

```
compareLeadingDigits("60", "6000");    // false
compareLeadingDigits("60", "60A");     // true
compareLeadingDigits("60", "60");      // true
compareLeadingDigits("1", "1");        // true
compareLeadingDigits("1", "1ABC");     // true
compareLeadingDigits("60", "A60");     // false
```